# Proving whether or not there exist $a,b$ such that $a+b>100$ and $a^2+b^2<1/1000$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

sorry for my English unfortunately I don't know English so well

Prove if the statement is true or false:
For two real positive numbers a,b:
a+b>100 and a^2+b^2<1/1000

I know the answer is false by instinct but I don't know how to prove it..

Comment: Good luck with this one.

Comment: I am sorry to say that there are no positive, real numbers $a$ and $b$ that satisfy both $a+b \gt 100$ and $a^2+b^2 \lt \frac 1{1000}$

Comment: I know but I got stuck to prove it... ><

Comment: one of $a$ or $b > 50$ this means that $a^2+b^2>2500$

Comment: Please make clear what is given, and what is wanted (not only in the title, but) also in the posted question. Own efforts to solve the problem are always welcome! We still wait for a question...

Comment: this is a statement that i need to prove if its true or if its false.The statement is that there are two real and positive numbers such as a and b so a+b>100 and a^2+b^2<1/1000

Comment: It is clear that there are no such $a,b$.  Please check your question....I expect that some of the details are incorrect.

Comment: It is false. You could use the RMS-AM inequality $\Biggr( \sqrt {\frac {a^2+b^2}2} \ge \frac {a+b}2 \Biggr)$ to deduce that $\frac {\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}2 \gt \frac {a+b}2 \implies \sqrt {a^2+b^2} \gt a+b$ and therefore $a^2+b^2  \ge \sqrt {a^2+b^2} \gt {a+b}$

Comment: Please refrain from doing such juvenile things such as typing in all caps, or saying "I hate this question", using too many exclamation points in a row, etc...

Comment: Additionally, the (education) tag should only be used for questions about educational pedagogy such as "*How soon after a topic is introduced is it okay to be given a test*" or "*Are true-false questions actually useful teaching tools?*"  The (education) tag is *not* meant to be used for questions that arose simply during your time going to school but are otherwise unrelated to questions about pedagogy.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition should tell you that if $a > 0; b>0$ then $a^2 > 0$ and $b^2 > 0$ so $a^2 < a^2 + b^2 < \frac 1{1000} < 1$ so $a < 1$ and $b^2 < a^2 + b^2 < \frac 1{1000} < 1$ so $b < 1$ so $a + b < 1 + 1 < 2$ and $a + b > 100$ is not possible.

There are no solutions.

More formally:  If $a + b > 100$ then $avg(a,b) = \frac {a + b}2 > 50$.  Let $avg(a,b) = c$ and let $k = c - a = \frac {a+b}2 - a = \frac {b -a }2$ so $a = c - k$ and $b - k = b - \frac {b-a}2 = \frac {a+b}2=c$ so $b = c + k$.

So $a^2 + b^2 = (c-k)^2 + (c + k)^2 = c^2 - 2ck + k^2 + c^2 +2ck + k^2 = 2c^2 +k^2 > 2c^2 > 2*50^2 = 5000> \frac 1{1000}$

So $a^2 + b^2 < \frac 1{1000}$ is most certainly impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Since a + b > 100, either a or b has to be greater than 1.

Therefore, either a^2 or b^2 has to be greater than 1.

Hence, the sum a^2 + b^2 cannot be less than 1/1000